# Manage environment variables in managed apache airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, airflow, mwaa

I am using aws managed apache airflow (also called mwaa) and try to set up the aws_key_id and aws_secret with `aws_default` in the connections. But the mwaa somehow creates an environment variable `AIRFLOW_CONN_AWS_DEFAULT` that values as `aws://` and it will always try to find the credentials from here first instead of in the connections.

[image]

So is there a way I can stop aws creating this environment variable by default?

Comment: Just to get a better understanding of your issue, what do you need the AWS key id and secret for? If you'd like to access other resources in the same AWS account, you could simply use an MWAA execution role and assign all required privileges to this role